# how do i remove <p> tag using jquery in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("#po").append("<p><%= j f.datetime_select :dtmRealshow%><a>Remove</a></p>");
    });   
});


<p id="po"></p>
<button id="btn1">+</button>
```

When i click on the `btn1` a new `datetime_select` field is added to the form.But i want to remove the parent `<p>` tag after clicking on the remove link.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a css class to anchor

```
$("#po").append("<p><%= j f.datetime_select :dtmRealshow%><a class='remove'>Remove</a></p>");  });
```

Then you can use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach to bind click handler to `anchor`.

```
$("#po").on('click', ".remove", function(){
    $(this).closest('p').remove();
});
```

Comment: @Udaykumardas, perhaps you could select Satpal's answer's as being correct any maybe give it an upvote too :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the parent `<p>` will remove it's `children` along with it.

If that's what you're looking for then try the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#po").append("<p><a id='remove'>Remove</a></p>");
        $("#remove").click(function() {
            $(this).closest('p').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

[Here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/om5dkerL/1/)